# Chart in multiple worksheet make file output corupted

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phpspreadsheet

Im create dynamic reporting using phpspreadsheet, when im create single worksheet with chart the output give the fine result.

when im create multiple worksheet with chart, the output saying "The file corupted", im trying find the answer on here , and try ob_end_clean(); before and after header , and the problem not fixed.

Here My Code :

```
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Chart;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeries;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\DataSeriesValues;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Legend;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\PlotArea;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Title;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
class Master_donor extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Master_donor_model');
    }
    function bulanprint(){
        $listbulan=$this->Master_donor_model->bulan();
        $test="2019";
        $a=0;
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        foreach($listbulan as $key){
            $datanya=$this->Master_donor_model->lapbulan($key->id_bulan,$test);
            $countdata=count($datanya);
            $oke=$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex($a);
            $oke->setCellValue('A1', 'Program Donor Darah Tahun '.$test);
            $oke->getStyle('A3:E3')->applyFromArray(
                [
                    'font' => ['bold' => true,],
                    'alignment' => ['horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,],
                ]
            );
            $oke->getStyle('A3:E'.($countdata+4))->applyFromArray(
                [
                    'alignment' => ['horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,],
                    'borders' => ['allBorders' => ['borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,],]
                ]
            );
            $oke->setCellValue('A3', 'No');
            $oke->setCellValue('B3', 'Site');
            $oke->setCellValue('C3', 'Target');
            $oke->setCellValue('D3', 'Jumlah Pendaftar');
            $oke->setCellValue('E3', 'Jumlah Kantong Darah');
            $oke->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
            $oke->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
            $oke->fromArray($datanya,NULL,'A4',true);
            $oke->mergeCells('A'.($countdata+4).':B'.($countdata+4));
            $oke->setCellValue('A'.($countdata+4), 'Total');
            $oke->setCellValue('C'.($countdata+4), '=SUM(C4:C'.($countdata+3).')');
            $oke->setCellValue('D'.($countdata+4), '=SUM(D4:D'.($countdata+3).')');
            $oke->setCellValue('E'.($countdata+4), '=SUM(E4:E'.($countdata+3).')');
            $dataSeriesLabels1 = [
                new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$E$3', null, 1), // Target
            ];
            $dataSeriesLabels2 = [
                new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$C$3', null, 1), // Jumlah Kantong
            ];
            $xAxisTickValues = [
                new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$B$4:$B$'.($countdata+3), null, $countdata), // Jan to Dec
            ];
            $dataSeriesValues1 = [
                new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$E$4:$E$'.($countdata+3), null, $countdata),
            ];

            // Build the dataseries
            $series1 = new DataSeries(
                DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,//plotType
                DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,//plotGrouping
                range(0, count($dataSeriesValues1) - 1),//plotOrder
                $dataSeriesLabels1,//plotLabel
                $xAxisTickValues,//plotCategory
                $dataSeriesValues1//plotValues
            );
            $series1->setPlotDirection(DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);
            $dataSeriesValues2 = [
                new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$C$4:$C$'.($countdata+3), null, $countdata),
            ];
            // Build the dataseries
            $series2 = new DataSeries(
                DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART, // plotType
                DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD, // plotGrouping
                range(0, count($dataSeriesValues2) - 1), // plotOrder
                $dataSeriesLabels2, // plotLabel
                [], // plotCategory
                $dataSeriesValues2// plotValues
            );
            $plotArea = new PlotArea(null, [$series1, $series2]);
            // Set the chart legend
            $legend = new Legend(Legend::POSITION_BOTTOM, null, false);
            $title = new Title('Donor Darah '.$key->bulan);
            $yAxisLabel = new Title('Jumlah Kantong Darah');
            // Create the chart
            $chart = new Chart(
                'chart1', // name
                $title, // title
                $legend, // legend
                $plotArea, // plotArea
                true, // plotVisibleOnly
                0, // displayBlanksAs
                null, // xAxisLabel
                $yAxisLabel  // yAxisLabel
            );
            // Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
            $chart->setTopLeftPosition('G3');
            $chart->setBottomRightPosition('Q22');
            $oke->addChart($chart);

            // Rename worksheet
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($key->bulan);
            if($a==11){
                break;
            }
            else{
                $spreadsheet->createSheet();
            }
            $a++;
        }
        // Save Excel 2007 file
        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex($a);
        $filename = "laporan_donor_".$test;
        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $filename .'.xlsx"'); 
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        ob_end_clean();
        $writer->save('php://output');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

The output should be having chart each worksheet

**Edit** : after limit the iteration to 8 it's work well , but my target limit is 11

***Note** my iteration start with 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on my query , so the excel file got fixed after my query produce not null values

Comment: The proper fix is to  

`DataSeries::EMPTY_AS_GAP, // displayBlanksAs`

However currently they appear to not support multiple worksheets with charts https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/2161

Comment: @brianlmerritt umm but i have multiple worksheet with a chart (line and bar in one chart)

Comment: Interesting!  Will have a look and see what is different.  What version of phpspreadsheet are you on?

Comment: Ahhh - I hadn't change the worksheet name reference so the code only worked if the data was in worksheet 1

Comment: Yes, but the above code doesn't work for example if the worksheet name was "worksheet2" because the worksheet name is hard wired comments.  I was using someone's email address as their name and for some reason the "@" and "." confused things.  I removed that part of the name and it seems ok now.